# Displaying data from relational ActiveRecord

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have 2 tables in my database:

**Prodik**
  prodik_id
  prodik_name

**Pelajaran**
  pelajaran_id
  pelajaran_name
  prodik_id

I want to display data in GridView with the columns:

|prodik_name|pelajaran|

I am new in Yii2, I have try my best, but still failed.

Comment: Sorry i mean |prodik_name|pelajaran_name| for displaying columns.

Comment: First of all, naming attributes like that considered bad practice. Please describe what you have tried and add code.

Answer (score 0):

First create model for you tables.

```
    use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Prodik extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'Prodik';
    }

    public function getPelajaran()
    {
        $this->hasOne(Pelajaran::className(), ['prodik_id' => 'prodik_id']);
    }
}
```

Create next model:

```
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Pelajaran extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'Pelajaran';
    }

}
```

Create controller:

```
public function actionGrid(){
    $query = Prodik::find()->with(['pelajaran']);
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,
            ]);

    return $this->render('grid', [            
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
}
```

Create view file.

```
<?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'prodik_name',
        [
            'value' => function ($data) {
                return $data['pelajaran']['pelajaran_name']; // or return $data->pelajaran->pelajaran_name; 
            }
        ]
    ]
]); ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you would get a `$data` array? I dont see that you are applying asArray property to be true in your query! Also I guess you can access relational fields by `'name' => 'relation.field'`

Comment: You are right. `$data` is a object. `return $data->pelajaran->pelajaran_name;`

Comment: Sory how i want to use the aggregate function like Count, sum and etc.?

Comment: Like that `Stat::find()->where(['status' => 1])->sum('status')`, `Stat::find()->where(['status' => 1])->count()` and etc. `Stat` - is a model Active Record. `->sum('status')` - `status` is a field to sum.